# ¿Cómo realizar un filtro de búsqueda en Laravel 9 utilizando múltiples columnas?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-9

Edit.Buen día tengan compañeros, podrían colaborarme con lo siguiente.
Estoy trabajando en Laravel 9 y PostgreSQL 12 necesito hacer una búsqueda, el asunto en cuestión es que los datos están en la tabla de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces lo que quiero es buscar por nombre completo, por el nombre de la empresa, o cualquier coincidencia
Ej:

1. Saori tovar
2. tovar
3. mi pc store

Lo que es lo siguiente

```
 $sale = Sale::with(['paymentReceivedItem'])
                ->join('contact', 'contact.id', '=', 'sale.contact')
                ->select(
                    'sale.id',
                    'sale.contact',
                    'sale.entNumberInvoice',
                    'sale.entDateExpedition',
                    'sale.entDateExpiration',
                    'sale.subTotal',
                    'sale.totalDiscount',
                    'sale.totalDiscountSubTotal',
                    'sale.totalTaxeSum',
                    'sale.total',
                    'sale.status',

                    'contact.businessName',
                    'contact.firstName',
                    'contact.secondName',
                    'contact.surname',
                    'contact.secondSurname',
                )
                ->where('sale.company', '=', Auth::user()->company)
                ->expedition($request['creation']) // SCOPE
                ->expiration($request['expiration']) // SCOPE
                ->name($request['client']) // SCOPE
                ->orderBy('sale.entNumberInvoice', 'desc')
                ->paginate(15);
```

Entonces básicamente lo que quiero es poder consultar por nombre completo concatenando las columnas

```
                        'contact.businessName',
                        'contact.firstName',
                        'contact.secondName',
                        'contact.surname',
                        'contact.secondSurname',
```

asi esta uno de mis scopes

```
public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
        if ($name) return $query->where('contact.firstName', 'ILIKE', '%' . $name . '%');
    }
```

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda brindada

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Comment: Eso es un buen comienzo... agrega tu código a la pregunta para poder orientarte mejor

Comment: Listo amigos ya agregue parte de mi código a la pregunta, soy nuevo en la plataforma es mi tercera consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de, voy a separar tu consulta de `$sale` en dos partes para no repetirnos.

```
    $query = Sale::with(['paymentReceivedItem'])
            ->join('contact', 'contact.id', '=', 'sale.contact')
            ->select(
                'sale.id',
                'sale.contact',
                'sale.entNumberInvoice',
                'sale.entDateExpedition',
                'sale.entDateExpiration',
                'sale.subTotal',
                'sale.totalDiscount',
                'sale.totalDiscountSubTotal',
                'sale.totalTaxeSum',
                'sale.total',
                'sale.status',

                'contact.businessName',
                'contact.firstName',
                'contact.secondName',
                'contact.surname',
                'contact.secondSurname',
            );

       $sale = $query
            ->where('sale.company', '=', Auth::user()->company)
            ->expedition($request['creation']) // SCOPE
            ->expiration($request['expiration']) // SCOPE
            ->name($request['client']) // SCOPE
            ->orderBy('sale.entNumberInvoice', 'desc')
            ->paginate(15);
```

Hay dos escenarios. En uno, tu frontend tiene una cajita de búsqueda y al llenarla y apretar enter, se gatilla un request que contiene el texto a buscar en un atributo determinado. Por ejemplo `search`.

En tu consulta pondrías entre medio de tus scopes un `where` condicional, usando el método `when` del query builder:

```
   $sale = $query
            ->when($request->search, function ($q, $search) {
              return $q->where('contact.businessName','ILIKE',"%{$search}%")
                  ->orWhere('contact.firstName','ILIKE',"%{$search}%")
                  ->orWhere('contact.secondName','ILIKE',"%{$search}%")
                  ->orWhere('contact.surname','ILIKE',"%{$search}%")
                  ->orWhere('contact.secondSurname','ILIKE',"%{$search}%")
           })
            ... otros scopes ...
            ->paginate(15);
```

Eso serviría para búsquedas como `Saori` o `Tovar` pero no para `Saori Tovar`. Para eso, serviría más que la subquery comparase contra la concatenación de tus campos buscables:

```
$sale = $query
  ->when($request->search, function ($q, $search) {
     return $q->where(
        DB::raw(
            "contact.businessName ||' '|| contact.firstName ||' '|| contact.secondName ||' '|| contact.surname ||' '|| contact.secondSurname"
        ),
        'like',
        "%{$search}%"
    );
 }) 
 ... otros scopes ...
 ->paginate(15);
```

Dije que había dos escenarios. En el segundo escenario, tu frontend permite filtrar mediante un input individual para cada campo. Acá no tendrías que concatenar, pero sí tendrías que tener tantos `when` como campos filtrables ofrezcas en tu frontend:

```
$sale= $query
      ->when($request->businessName, function($q, $businessName) {
          return $q->where('contact.businessName','ILIKE',"%{$businessName}%");
       })
       >when($request->firstName, function($q, $firstName) {
          return $q->where('contact.firstName','ILIKE',"%{$firstName}%");
       })
        ... otros scopes ...
       ->paginate(15);
```

Esa lógica repetida quedaría mejor encapsulada recorriendo un array de campos filtrables:

```
   $query = Sale::with(...)->select(...);

   foreach(['businessName','firstName','secondName' etc] as $campo) {
     $query = $query->when($request->get($campo), function($q, $valor) use ($campo) {
        return $q->where(sprintf('contact.',$campo),'ILIKE',"%{$valor}%");
     });
    }
    $sale = $query->where(...)
            ->expedition(...)
            ...etc etc ...
            ->paginate(15);
```

En este segundo escenario, llenar dos casillas del frontend no se comporta como un OR, sino que devuelve los resultados que coincidan en todos los campos enviados.